# PHP League Container : Strategy pattern

Tags: php, thephpleague

I'm using the [PHP League Container](https://container.thephpleague.com) and I want to implement a strategy pattern.

I want to connect to an external service with a different client class depending on the `$version` parameter that is passed to my adapter.  I want to pass the client in to the adapter as a dependency.

How can I get PHP league container to replace the definition of an interface with a new class at runtime?

Comment: I'm not really good at names of specific patterns, but I'd think this would lend itself better to a factory pattern which would be much easier to test. The factory is a first-class object in your system, it inspects the provided version, and then doles out the appropriate class as needed.